# continuous infinitive or bare continuous infinitive n 'It is important that the focus of training courses **be** towards ...'?

Tags: infinitives

Why in this sentence is the bare continuous infinitive used?

It is important that the focus of training courses be towards enabling employees to competently perform tasks
*It is important that the focus of training courses **be** towards **enabling** employees to competently perform tasks.*

Comment: It's not. There's no infinitive (it's a subjunctive), and there's no progressive/continuous aspect (_enabling_ is a gerund). Progressive constructions don't allow prepositions between the auxiliary and the participle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"*It is important that the focus of training courses **be** towards **enabling** employees to competently perform tasks".*

In this sentence, the verb is **'be'** and it is in the **subjunctive mood**; the word 'towards' is a preposition which is placed before the verbal noun (gerund) 'enabling'.

> **Subjunctive:** The subjunctive a special kind of present tense which has no -s in the third person singular. It is sometimes used,
>   especially in American English, after words which express the idea that
>   something is important or desirable (e.g. suggest, recommend, ask,
>   insist, vital, essential, important, advice).

E.g It is important that every **child** **have** the same educational opportunities.

It is important that **Helen be** present when we sign the papers.

The forms ***I were*** and ***he/she/it were*** used after ***if*** and ***wish*** are also a kind of subjunctive.

E.g. *If **I were** you I should stop smoking.
       I wish **it were** Saturday.*

Subjunctive are also use in certain fixed phrases:

***God save*** the King!  **God bless** you.

(Based on *Michael Swan's PEU*).

Comment: This has all been covered before on ELU, mahmud. Plus the school of thought attesting that English has no subjunctive mood as such.